# Problems with global variables ((python))

Tags: python-2.7, module, global-variables

I have a problem with my global variables in my code. In SCRIPT1.py I use many variables from a little document config.py which only contains variables which I also need in other modules of my code. But when running my SCRIPT1.py I get an error (ERROR). I have no idea why it doesn't work with config.(name of variable)... I found this solution to have your variables in all of your modules on stack overflow with a lot of good votes. What am I doing wrong?

First my code contained config.costSurfaceA in stead of costSurfaceArray (for ex in 'def createPath') but when running it with this variable, it gave me a syntax error because of the dot in 'config.costSurfaceA'. I replaced it all by 'costSurfaceArray' and did this in the if statement 'config.costSurfaceA = costSurfaceArray' just to get it as a variable. But I have the feeling this is all to much work for nothing..

Thanks in avance for helping me! I know it is a lot of code but I think it's all important for understanding..

SCRIPT1.py

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr
from skimage.graph import route_through_array
import numpy as np
import Save_Array_To_Excel_01
import config

def ask_costsurfacepath_path():
    config.costsurfacepath = input('please enter the system path where to find the cost-surface-IMG file (ex: /Users/PeterVanvoorden/Documents/GroepT/Thesis/Branched_Testfile.img): ')

def ask_outputpath_path():
    config.outputpath = input('please enter the system path where to save the outputpath IMG file (ex: /Users/PeterVanvoorden/Documents/GroepT/Thesis/Branched_Testfile.img): ')


def raster2array(rasterfn):
    print 'raster2array'
    raster = gdal.Open(rasterfn)
    band = raster.GetRasterBand(1)
    array = band.ReadAsArray()
    return array  

def coord2pixelOffset(rasterfn,x,y):
    print 'coord2pixelOffset'
    raster = gdal.Open(rasterfn)
    geotransform = raster.GetGeoTransform()
    originX = geotransform[0] # East/West location of Upper Left corner
    originY = geotransform[3] # North/South location of Upper Left corner
    pixelWidth = geotransform[1] # X pixel size
    pixelHeight = geotransform[5] # Y pixel size
    xOffset = int((x - originX)/pixelWidth)
    yOffset = int((y - originY)/pixelHeight)
    return xOffset,yOffset

def createPath(CostSurfacefn,costSurfaceArray,startCoord,stopCoord):   
    print 'creatpath'
    # coordinates to array index
    startCoordX = startCoord[0]
    startCoordY = startCoord[1]
    startIndexX,startIndexY = coord2pixelOffset(CostSurfacefn,startCoordX,startCoordY)

    stopCoordX = stopCoord[0]
    stopCoordY = stopCoord[1]
    stopIndexX,stopIndexY = coord2pixelOffset(CostSurfacefn,stopCoordX,stopCoordY)

    # create path
    indices, weight = route_through_array(costSurfaceArray, (startIndexY,startIndexX), (stopIndexY,stopIndexX),geometric=True,fully_connected=True)
    indices = np.array(indices).T
    path = np.zeros_like(costSurfaceArray)
    path[indices[0], indices[1]] = 1
    return path

def array2raster(newRasterfn,rasterfn,array):
    print 'array2raster'
    raster = gdal.Open(rasterfn)
    geotransform = raster.GetGeoTransform()
    originX = geotransform[0] # East/West location of Upper Left corner
    originY = geotransform[3] # North/South location of Upper Left corner
    pixelWidth = geotransform[1] # X pixel size
    pixelHeight = geotransform[5] # Y pixel size
    cols = array.shape[1]
    rows = array.shape[0]

    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    outRaster = driver.Create(newRasterfn, cols, rows, gdal.GDT_Byte)
    outRaster.SetGeoTransform((originX, pixelWidth, 0, originY, 0, pixelHeight))
    outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(1)
    outband.WriteArray(array)
    outRasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
    outRasterSRS.ImportFromWkt(raster.GetProjectionRef())
    outRaster.SetProjection(outRasterSRS.ExportToWkt())
    outband.FlushCache()    

def main(CostSurfacefn,outputPathfn,startCoord,stopCoord):

    print 'main'

    costSurfaceArray = raster2array(CostSurfacefn) # creates array from cost surface raster

    config.costSurfaceA = costSurfaceArray

    config.pathArray = createPath(CostSurfacefn,costSurfaceArray,startCoord,stopCoord) # creates path array

    Save_Array_To_Excel_01.Save_Array(config.pathArray) # Save Array to csv file

    array2raster(outputPathfn,CostSurfacefn,config.pathArray) # converts path array to raster


if __name__ == "__main__":

    ask_costsurfacepath_path()
    ask_outputpath_path()
    CostSurfacefn = config.costsurfacepath
    print config.costsurfacepath
    startCoord = (config.startX,config.startY)
    stopCoord = (config.stopX,config.stopY)
    outputPathfn = config.outputpath

    main(CostSurfacefn,outputPathfn,startCoord,stopCoord)
```

config.py

```
# Configuration file with all global variables

# number of properties
number =  None

# different permutations of properties
permutations = list()

# properties array containing:
# * first column = ID first property [0]
# * second column = ID second property [1]
# * third column = distance between two properties [2]
# * forth column = estimated cost [3]
properties_array = None

# lowest price until now
lowest_price = 10**10000

# path with this lowest price
lowest_path = None

# current price (needs to be compared with lowest price)
current_price = 0

# current path (needs to be compared with lowest path)
current_path = [1]

# path to place where to save properties list
plist_path = None

# Array of the path
pathArray = None

# Array of the map
costSurfaceA = None

# current start X coordinate
startX = 0

# current start Y coordinate
startY = 0

# current stop X coordinate
stopX = 0

# current stop Y coordinate
stopY = 0

# path to costsurface IMG file
costsurfacepath = 0

# path to output path from Least cost path analysis
outputpath = 0
```

ERROR

```
please enter the system path where to put the file as a STRING (ex: /Users/PeterVanvoorden/Documents/GroepT/Thesis/Branched_Testfile.csv): '/User/PeterVanvoorden/Desktop/Shell.csv'

You entered: /User/PeterVanvoorden/Desktop/Shell.csv

please enter the system path where to find the cost-surface-IMG file (ex: /Users/PeterVanvoorden/Documents/GroepT/Thesis/Branched_Testfile.img): '/User/PeterVanvoorden/Desktop/clipsmall.img'
please enter the system path where to save the outputpath IMG file (ex: /Users/PeterVanvoorden/Documents/GroepT/Thesis/Branched_Testfile.img): '/User/PeterVanvoorden/Desktop/Shellimg.img'
/User/PeterVanvoorden/Desktop/clipsmall.img
main
raster2array

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PeterVanvoorden/Documents/GroepT/Thesis/f_python_standalone/python_files/Working_Files/Least_cost_path_analysis_01_outputArray.py", line 97, in <module>
    main(CostSurfacefn,outputPathfn,startCoord,stopCoord)
  File "/Users/PeterVanvoorden/Documents/GroepT/Thesis/f_python_standalone/python_files/Working_Files/Least_cost_path_analysis_01_outputArray.py", line 76, in main
    costSurfaceArray = raster2array(CostSurfacefn) # creates array from cost surface raster
  File "/Users/PeterVanvoorden/Documents/GroepT/Thesis/f_python_standalone/python_files/Working_Files/Least_cost_path_analysis_01_outputArray.py", line 17, in raster2array
    band = raster.GetRasterBand(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'
```

Comment: What is the value of raster after this? raster = gdal.Open(rasterfn)

Comment: The value for raster is None.

Comment: Are you sure `CostSurfacefn` is supposed to be 0? (from the config) From the name, it sounds to me like a function or a lambda. Also I don't think this naming convention is suitable to Python. We only use camel-case for class names and such in Python. Variable names and method/function names are generally snake-case

Comment: There is no CostSurfacefn in config.py. I made costsurfacepath = 0 in config.py because I just want to declare its existence and than change it to the string with the needed path in the SCRIPT1.py

I know the naming is not really good.. But I just started to learn programming a month ago and I have the feeling that the naming will not make any difference to what it should do.. I'm gonna try to do it with the conventional way of writing but for now I just want to focus on getting it working

Comment: is it possible to declare a variable without a value? I mean, that the variable exists and that it gets a value only after the first time it is used in the code?

Comment: But why would you want to use such a variable in the config file? You should use it locally and pass around. Naming, I mention because it was a little confusing to read. And in Python, nope... but you can always assign the variable to None.

Comment: but how can I pass it around afterwards? I use the config file to put all the variables that I need in other files.. I don't know how to 'pass them around'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass around like this.

```
def ask_costsurfacepath_path():
    costsurfacepath = input('please enter ...')
    return costsurfacepath

... in __name__ == '__main__'
CostSurfacefn = ask_costsurfacepath_path()
...
```

Comment: but, in this way, is it possible to use the value of costsurfacepath in another file? for example in a file called SCRIPT2.py? Because thats why I am using the config file... Not to use it in a different function in the same file but in order to use it easily in another file.

Comment: If, for example you are calling some function in the second file that you import like, `from SCRIPT2 import some_func` then of course you can pass the variable as an argument to `some_func`

Comment: But I mean, how can I do this?

SCRIPT1.py
`def function1(): some code resulting in variable VAR = /Users/PV.csv return VAR`

and I want to use this variable VAR in SCRIPS2.py


Should I than do:

SCRIPT2.py
`import SCRIPT1`

????

I just want to get the value of the variable, not something like:

SCRIPT2.py
`import SCRIPT1 BLI = SCRIPT1.function1()`

because, than I'll be running this script again in stead of just using the value of VAR which already exists because SCRIPT1.py was already executed..